# Python Related error while i am trying to knit my Rmd file in R studio

Tags: python, r

[image]

here is my code:

````
---
title: "Expert advice from experts"
author:
- familyname: abc
  othernames: xyz
  address: Monash University, Clayton 
  qualifications: Master of Business Analytics
email: fghj0017@student.monash.edu
phone: 0497891234
department: Department of\newline Econometrics &\newline Business Statistics
organization: Monash Univeristy 
bibliography: references.bib
biblio-style: authoryear-comp
linestretch: 1.5
output:
  monash::report:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 5
    fig_width: 8
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    citation_package: biblatex
    toc: true
---

```{r setup, include= FALSE, message=  FALSE, warning = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, eval = TRUE)
```

# Executive Summary 


# Introduction 

Lifestyle can indicate a lot about a person's life. For this analysis I have selected 5 Major factors that a human get addicted to very quickly and are related to his or her bad habits. I will be analyzing 30 years of data of country India and observe trends and will try to conclude the result of the analysis.

The analysis is based on an open data that is available on "Our World In Data" and the aim of the analysis is to produce a report that provides an overview on how lifestyle affects the mortality rates in India.


# Body


## Methodology 


## Results


## Discussion, conclusion and recommendations


# Reference 

list all the references here
````

I need a pdf report after knitting the file

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages. Copy the text and add them as codeblock to your question.